# No head rule defined for AP when parsing a sentence using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, text-parsing, parse-tree

I try to get the head word of some sentences. But I face `No head rule defined` exception for different phrase types. As some phrase types are not that important to me, I can ignore tham by an if clause. But, for example, `AP` (Adjective Phrase) is important to me and I would like to have the head word of such phrases. Any help or idea about that?

I'm using the following code:

```
    HeadFinder hf = new UniversalSemanticHeadFinder();
    hf.determineHead(oneTree, mainTree);
```

I'm using the latest version of `Stanford CoreNLP` (3.8) from my `java` code and the code works perfectly with English sentences.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a different set of constituent labels. The head finder was developed for trees in the Penn Treebank (PTB) format, which, for example, use the label `ADJP` for adjective phrases. You can find the set of PTB labels and their descriptions on [this page](http://www.surdeanu.info/mihai/teaching/ista555-fall13/readings/PennTreebankConstituents.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean that the Stanford CoreNLP HeadFinder is not developed for German or am I using the wrong models? I'm using "german-fast.tagger" and "germanSR.ser.gz" for German language. These models give me "AP" for "Adjective Phrase". Am I using something wrongly?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, one has to develop a head finder for each treebank annotation scheme, and we don't have a head finder for any of the German treebanks. That being said, I think it shouldn't be too hard to adapt the `UniversalSemanticHeadFinder()` to German. (If you end up implementing this, please share it with us --  we'd be happy to include it in CoreNLP )